# Turn on Shift key when spacebar is pressed in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

How do I programmatically turn on the shift key (so that the next character is uppercase) on the keyboard when the user presses the spacebar for a UITextField?

In addition, I do not want any spaces in the text field such that the user is able to type an entry like this: "ThisIsATest"

I currently use the following to detect if the spacebar is pressed, and return false to avoid spaces, but I dont know how to toggle the shift key:

```
// check if string in UITextField is a space
if (string == " "){ 
// do not return a space
return false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

This is tested and does print "ThisIsATest" when you press space bar after each word. I'm not that good with Swift yet, so this snippet is in Obj-C. It's pretty straightforward. Be sure to set your textField's delegate to ViewController either in code or in IB.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL shouldCapitalizeNextChar;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.shouldCapitalizeNextChar = YES;

}


- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {


    if ([string isEqualToString:@" "]) {

        self.shouldCapitalizeNextChar = YES;

        return NO;
    }

    if (self.shouldCapitalizeNextChar) {

        NSString *capitalizedChar = [string capitalizedString];

        textField.text = [textField.text stringByAppendingString:capitalizedChar];

        self.shouldCapitalizeNextChar = NO;

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}


@end
```

As before, this won't work with copied and pasted text. But it should help you to get the idea.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

A UITextField knows how to autocapitalize each word, if that's what you want in your app just use:

Obj-c

```
textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
```

Swift

```
textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.Words
```

Be aware that this is just a suggestion to the user, he/she can override it by pressing shift. It won't work if Paste option is used either.

Comment: I think that UITextField recognises words based on the addition of a space (from the spacebar). for this case the spacebar is disabled so the only way I can think of is to be able to turn on the shift key. I dont mind if the user decides to override it by pressing shift again.

Comment: @spigen see updated answer. It does not light up the shift key, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set autoCapitalizationType of a textField. For your requirement you need to set `Words`

**From The [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInputTraits/autocapitalizationType) :**

> **Discussion** This property determines at what times the Shift key is automatically pressed, thereby making the typed character a capital
>   letter. The default value for this property is
>   UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences.

**SWIFT**

```
enum UITextAutocapitalizationType : Int {
    case None
    case Words
    case Sentences
    case AllCharacters
}
```

> **Constants (For All : Available in iOS 2.0 and later.)**
>
> `None` : Do not capitalize any text automatically.
>
> `Words` : Capitalize the first letter of each word automatically.
>
> `Sentences` : Capitalize the first letter of each sentence automatically.
>
> `AllCharacters` : Capitalize all characters automatically.

**OBJECTIVE C**

```
typedef enum : NSInteger {
   UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone,
   UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords,
   UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences,
   UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters,
} UITextAutocapitalizationType;
```

> **Constants (For All : Available in iOS 2.0 and later.)**
>
> `UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone` : Do not capitalize any text automatically.
>
> `UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords` : Capitalize the first letter of each word automatically.
>
> `UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences` : Capitalize the first letter of each sentence automatically.
>
> `UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters` : Capitalize all characters automatically.

Just like:

**SWIFT**

```
textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.Words
```

**OBJECTIVE C**

```
textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
```

Enjoy....

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is

string == @" " is wrong.

Equality for strings is done using:

[string isEqualToString:@" "]

I hope it will help:)

Comment: That would be correct for Objective-C, but in Swift strings are compared with `==`.